# Using STL vector to create an array causes an error

Tags: programming, c++

I have installed the STL for arduino, and it has been working fine. Then I tried to create a vector using a custom class, and it gave me a massive error message. When using it on primitive data types (ex. int) it works fine, but in any one of my own classes (including classes from sample code) it gives this error:

```
Arduino: 1.6.3 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Build options changed, rebuilding all



C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w - fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD   -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10603 -  DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files   (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files   (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard   C:\Users\OWNER\AppData\Local\Temp\build7240665633604233053.tmp\Navigation.cpp -o    C:\Users\OWNER\AppData\Local\Temp\build7240665633604233053.tmp\Navigation.cpp.o 

In file included from c:\program files     (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\vector:33:0,

                 from Navigation.ino:2:

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_construct.h: In instantiation   of 'void std::__destroy_aux(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, __false_type)   [with _ForwardIterator = Obstacle*]':

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_construct.h:78:55:   required  from 'void std::__destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Tp*) [with  _ForwardIterator = Obstacle*; _Tp = Obstacle]'

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_construct.h:83:51:   required from 'void std::_Destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = Obstacle*]'

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_construct.h:115:27:   required  from 'void std::destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = Obstacle*]'

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:284:42:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::~vector() [with _Tp = Obstacle; _Alloc = std::allocator<Obstacle>]'

Navigation.ino:36:23:   required from here

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_construct.h:66:22: error: 'destroy' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]

     destroy(&*__first);

                  ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_construct.h:114:13: note: 'template<class _ForwardIterator> void std::destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator)' declared here, later in the translation unit

 inline void destroy(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last) {

             ^

Error compiling.
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the code:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <pnew.cpp>

class Test {
public:
    int i;
};
std::vector<Test> test;
```

Change the last line to

```
std::vector<Test&> test
```

and:

```
        Arduino: 1.6.3 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino Uno"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -std=gnu++11 -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10603 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Users\OWNER\AppData\Local\Temp\build7240665633604233053.tmp\Navigation.cpp -o C:\Users\OWNER\AppData\Local\Temp\build7240665633604233053.tmp\Navigation.cpp.o 

In file included from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\vector:35:0,

                 from Navigation.ino:2:

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h: In instantiation of 'class std::_Vector_alloc_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&>, true>':

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:101:8:   required from 'struct std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >'

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:155:7:   required from 'class std::vector<Obstacle&>'

Navigation.ino:36:24:   required from here

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:89:8: error: forming pointer to reference type 'Obstacle&'

   _Tp* _M_start;

        ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:90:8: error: forming pointer to reference type 'Obstacle&'

   _Tp* _M_finish;

        ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:91:8: error: forming pointer to reference type 'Obstacle&'

   _Tp* _M_end_of_storage;

        ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:94:8: error: forming pointer to reference type 'Obstacle&'

   _Tp* _M_allocate(size_t __n)

        ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:96:8: error: forming pointer to reference type 'Obstacle&'

   void _M_deallocate(_Tp* __p, size_t __n)

        ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h: In instantiation of 'class std::vector<Obstacle&>':

Navigation.ino:36:24:   required from here

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:165:23: error: forming pointer to reference type 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::value_type {aka Obstacle&}'

   typedef value_type* pointer;

                       ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:166:29: error: forming pointer to reference type 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::value_type {aka Obstacle&}'

   typedef const value_type* const_pointer;

                             ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:167:23: error: forming pointer to reference type 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::value_type {aka Obstacle&}'

   typedef value_type* iterator;

                       ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:168:29: error: forming pointer to reference type 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::value_type {aka Obstacle&}'

   typedef const value_type* const_iterator;

                             ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:178:49: error: forming pointer to reference type 'Obstacle&'

   typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;

                                                 ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:179:43: error: forming pointer to reference type 'Obstacle&'

   typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;

                                           ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:189:16: error: no members matching 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::_Base {aka std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >}::_M_allocate' in 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::_Base {aka struct std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >}'

   using _Base::_M_allocate;

                ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:190:16: error: no members matching 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::_Base {aka std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >}::_M_deallocate' in 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::_Base {aka struct std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >}'

   using _Base::_M_deallocate;

                ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:191:16: error: no members matching 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::_Base {aka std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >}::_M_start' in 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::_Base {aka struct std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >}'

   using _Base::_M_start;

                ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:192:16: error: no members matching 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::_Base {aka std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >}::_M_finish' in 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::_Base {aka struct std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >}'

   using _Base::_M_finish;

                ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:193:16: error: no members matching 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::_Base {aka std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >}::_M_end_of_storage' in 'std::vector<Obstacle&>::_Base {aka struct std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >}'

   using _Base::_M_end_of_storage;

                ^

In file included from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\iosfwd:22:0,

                 from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\iterator:35,

                 from Navigation.ino:1:

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_alloc.h: In instantiation of 'class std::allocator<Obstacle&>':

Navigation.ino:36:24:   required from here

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_alloc.h:638:22: error: forming pointer to reference type 'Obstacle&'

   typedef _Tp*       pointer;

                      ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_alloc.h:639:22: error: forming pointer to reference type 'Obstacle&'

   typedef const _Tp* const_pointer;

                      ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_alloc.h:658:8: error: forming pointer to reference type 'Obstacle&'

   _Tp* allocate(size_type __n, const void* = 0) {

        ^

Navigation.ino: In constructor 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = Obstacle&; _Alloc = std::allocator<Obstacle&>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<Obstacle&>]':

Navigation.ino:36:24: note:   when instantiating default argument for call to std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = Obstacle&; _Alloc = std::allocator<Obstacle&>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<Obstacle&>]

In file included from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\vector:35:0,

                 from Navigation.ino:2:

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h: In instantiation of 'std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::~_Vector_base() [with _Tp = Obstacle&; _Alloc = std::allocator<Obstacle&>]':

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:240:16:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = Obstacle&; _Alloc = std::allocator<Obstacle&>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<Obstacle&>]'

Navigation.ino:36:24:   required from here

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:117:21: error: 'struct std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >' has no member named '_M_deallocate'

   ~_Vector_base() { this->_M_deallocate(_Base::_M_start, _Base::_M_end_of_storage - _Base::_M_start); }

                     ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:117:21: error: '_M_start' is not a member of 'std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >::_Base {aka std::_Vector_alloc_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&>, true>}'

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:117:83: error: '_M_start' is not a member of 'std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >::_Base {aka std::_Vector_alloc_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&>, true>}'

   ~_Vector_base() { this->_M_deallocate(_Base::_M_start, _Base::_M_end_of_storage - _Base::_M_start); }

                                                                                   ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:117:83: error: '_M_end_of_storage' is not a member of 'std::_Vector_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&> >::_Base {aka std::_Vector_alloc_base<Obstacle&, std::allocator<Obstacle&>, true>}'

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h: In instantiation of 'std::_Vector_alloc_base<_Tp, _Allocator, true>::_Vector_alloc_base(const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = Obstacle&; _Allocator = std::allocator<Obstacle&>; std::_Vector_alloc_base<_Tp, _Allocator, true>::allocator_type = std::allocator<Obstacle&>]':

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:110:54:   required from 'std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Vector_base(const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = Obstacle&; _Alloc = std::allocator<Obstacle&>; std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<Obstacle&>]'

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:240:16:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = Obstacle&; _Alloc = std::allocator<Obstacle&>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<Obstacle&>]'

Navigation.ino:36:24:   required from here

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:85:53: error: using invalid field 'std::_Vector_alloc_base<_Tp, _Allocator, true>::_M_start'

     : _M_start(0), _M_finish(0), _M_end_of_storage(0) 

                                                     ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:85:53: error: using invalid field 'std::_Vector_alloc_base<_Tp, _Allocator, true>::_M_finish'

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:85:53: error: using invalid field 'std::_Vector_alloc_base<_Tp, _Allocator, true>::_M_end_of_storage'

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h: In instantiation of 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::~vector() [with _Tp = Obstacle&; _Alloc = std::allocator<Obstacle&>]':

Navigation.ino:36:24:   required from here

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:284:42: error: '_M_start' was not declared in this scope

   ~vector() { destroy(_M_start, _M_finish); }

                                          ^

c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\stl_vector.h:284:42: error: '_M_finish' was not declared in this scope

Error compiling.
```

Comment: Does the error occur on a POD class? say, a class with just one public integer member and the default constructor/deconstructor? Also, if it works for primatives, it should work with pointers to your class.

Comment: Please post the code, not just the error message. Make up a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, it occurs on a POD class, and it returns an even larger error message upon trying to use a pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::vector<Test&> test
```

Yes, well I doubt you can make a vector of references. A vector of **pointers** I could believe.

See, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references

Comment: I'm too used to java